# How to install spacy in pycharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This error message occurs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4S30.jpg)

Command "C:\Users\Personal\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe c:\users\personal\pycharmprojects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg\pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\Personal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ovv17p4w\overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel>0.32.0.<0.33.0 Cython cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0 preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0 murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0 thinc==7.0.0.dev6" failed with error code 1 in None

Answer (score 6):

Go to Preference -> Python Interpreter -> click + -> search for spacy and install

After installation, while writing code, include the following

import spacy

spacy.cli.download("en_core_web_sm")

Comment: where is 'preference'  in Pycharm ?

Comment: @blah On Mac, it's under PyCharm menu on the top left corner

Answer (score 0):

you can use binary or wheel file for installing spacy package. just go to the python environment if u have env\scripts and pip command to install the binary file of spacy.
you can get the binary file from

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#

just download the file that supports your system and use it